# ExtJS 5 Charts: Chart works in fiddle but not in application

Tags: extjs5, extjs-chart

A simple chart I made works fine in Sencha Fiddle ([see here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ck7)) but will not run in my application. the error I can see in Chrome Developer Tools is:

`*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined*` at **ext-all.js:19**

I included `ext-charts.js` and even `Cartesian.js` to see if this will help, but no cigar.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Components/Sencha/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Components/Sencha/packages/ext-charts/build/ext-charts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Components/Sencha/packages/ext-charts/src/chart/series/Cartesian.js"></script>
```

Anyone has an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out `ext-charts` is the old charts package from ExtJS 4 and `sencha-charts` is the new charts package introduced in ExtJS 5.

Sencha Fiddle with ExtJS version lower than 5.0.1 won´t render the charts because the package is missing.

My version is 5.0.1 so loading the `sencha-charts` package solved the problem.